# Are SAM missiles or interceptors better for shooting down bombers?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

With BD Armory, what are the pros and cons of using interceptor fighter jets or surface-to-air missiles for defending the KSC from bombers?  Is one better than the other, or should they be used together?